# Space fraction vertically

Tags: spacing, fractions

I have an

```
$$y=e^{\frac{a}{2}}$$
```

But I do not like the fraction line that partially overlaps with the 2.
How can I solve it?

Comment: You can write `y=e^{a/2}` instead.

Comment: Use `e^{a/2}`; two story fractions in exponents should be avoided.

Comment: or `\exp(\frac{a}{2})`

Comment: Use `\[...\]`instead of `$$...$$`

Answer (score 7):

Here's a list of possibilities:

[image]

The very first term is from your code. The second one use a `\mathstrut` directive inside the denominator to increase the vertical offset at which the entire `\frac` term is placed. The third solution uses inline fractional notation instead of `\frac`. The final two solutions use `\exp(...)` notation, where the material inside the parentheses can be either a `\frac` expression (with slightly enlarged parentheses) or an inline fraction expression. The parentheses around the `\tfrac{a}{2}` term are optional.

Choose whichever form you like best. Of course, what's "best" should depend in no small part on whether the equation appears in display math or in inline math material.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for "\tfrac" macro
\begin{document}
\[
y = e^{\frac{a}{2}}               % original form
  = e^{\frac{a}{2\mathstrut}}     % \mathstrut method 
  = e^{a/2}                       % infix fraction 
  = \exp\bigl(\tfrac{a}{2}\bigr)  % \exp notation with \frac
  = \exp(a/2)                     % \exp notation with infix fraction 
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: An empty subscript does nothing; it's an empty *superscript* that pushes the subscript a bit down.

Comment: I think you don't need parenthesis in `\exp \tfrac{a}{2}`.

Comment: @yo' - I've added a sentence to mention that the parentheses may be omitted when using `\exp` notation.

Answer (score 1):

You can force `displaystyle` although in this case may be a bit too large for your argument. You can try

```
$$y=  e^{\displaystyle\frac{a}{2}}$$
```

which yields to

[image]

But as @egreg said, fractions in exponent are neither usual nor recommended. Perhaps you may want to try something like this

```
$$y=e^{\displaystyle a/2}$$
```

with that, you can achieve something like this

[image]

that you may like more.

Comment: Please, why do you believe the font size change is any useful? I ask sincerely, I want to know the source of this belief so that I can help getting rid of it.

Comment: I would heartily discourage ever setting an exponent in `\displaystyle` or `\textstyle`. The resulting formula is at least ambiguous. I find the first form appalling, to be honest, the second one is just wrong.